# Running "homebrew upgrade [specific formulae] upgraded a lot more, why?

Tags: homebrew, upgrade

So I needed to upgrade `youtube-dl`, and ran `brew upgrade youtube-dl`. While it was running, homebrew decided it needed to upgrade a lot more stuff, including all of my installed PHP versions... And now, none of them works like they should anymore (error messages in cli, modules not loaded, etc.).

I'm going to go on and probably reformat my machine to have a clean slate, but I wonder *why* running `brew upgrade` while explicitely giving the package to upgrade would update others. I understand dependencies, but I highly doubt that `youtube-dl` is dependent on PHP 7.4 *and* PHP 8.0, and others.

Is there a flag I missed? Anything else?

Comment: You don't need to reformat. Just delete the Homebrew directory

Comment: No, but something `youtube-dl` is dependent on is likely dependent on something else which is dependent on something else.  That's the idea of a dependency tree.  I'm sure that homebrew has something that will show you the dependency tree, it can't be *so* broken that it does not.  It also has `--dry-run` which should always be used before actually letting it do anything.

Comment: @mmmmmm yes, I'm aware, I could probably also just uninstall/reinstall my packages, but I also love a clean slate ;-)

Comment: @MarcWilson good call on the dry run ! I knew about it, but I would have never tought about it !

Comment: I realize this is not helpful in this particular instance, but if you want to avoid this particular situation in the future, you can install youtube-dl from https://www.yt-dl.org and then update it independently using `youtube-dl -U` which will update only what it needs, without using `brew` at all. Good luck!

Comment: None of the existing answers explicitly addresses why updating formulae often *breaks* stuff. This is quite common with Python, for instance. As far as I'm aware the reason is mixing of installer systems (e.g. Homebrew & pip), and the fact that installed executables often hard-code paths to libraries and interpreters, which include the version string. It's an infuriating situation. Unfortunately there's no simple solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Homebrew FAQ](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ):

> ## Why does brew upgrade  also upgrade a bunch of other stuff?
>
> Homebrew doesn’t support arbitrary mixing and matching of formula
> versions, so everything a formula depends on, and everything that
> depends on it in turn, needs to be upgraded to the latest version as
> that’s the only combination of formulae we test. As a consequence any
> given `upgrade` or `install` command can upgrade many other (seemingly
> unrelated) formulae, if something important like `python` or `openssl`
> also needed an upgrade.
>
> ## How do I stop certain formulae from being updated?
>
> To stop something from being updated/upgraded:
>
> `brew pin <formula>`
>
> To allow that formulae to update again:
>
> `brew unpin <formula>`
>
> Note that pinned, outdated formulae that another
> formula depends on need to be upgraded when required, as we do not
> allow formulae to be built against outdated versions. If this is not
> desired, you can instead `brew extract` to maintain your own copy of the
> formula in a tap.

Comment: I swear to god, the yellow in bown is doing something to my eyes, I can't believe I looked over that part !

Answer (score 10):

To see the dependency tree of a Homebrew package, use `brew deps --tree <package>`:

```
$ brew deps --tree --include-build youtube-dl
youtube-dl
└── python@3.9
    ├── pkg-config
    ├── gdbm
    ├── mpdecimal
    ├── openssl@1.1
    ├── readline
    ├── sqlite
    │   └── readline
    └── xz
```

`youtube-dl`, `php` and `php@7.4` all depend on `python@3.9`. I *could* imagine that updating `youtube-dl` triggered an update of `python@3.9` which was incompatible with the installed versions of `php`/`php@7.4`, therefore triggering an update of those packages as well.

Comment: Thank you for the command to see dependencies, it'll be useful !

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because `brew` automatically upgraded other packages that use the dependencies of `youtube-dl` that were upgraded.

You can disable that behavior by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALLED_DEPENDENTS_CHECK:

```
export HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALLED_DEPENDENTS_CHECK=1
```

You can show which packages depend on a specific package (these are called dependents):

```
brew uses --recursive --installed python
```